# Very strange Drupal 7 404 behaviour

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I am having some very strange behaviour in D7 that I have not seen before. I have migrated a new site from my dev machine to a test machine, so code and DB are identical. On the dev machine (Ubuntu 13.04, Apache, PHP 5.5.3), everything works fine, but on the test box which is a Raspberry Pi running PHP 5.4.4 on Raspbian, I seem to get 404 errors on form submission. What seems to happen is that the form is not processed and the original page is returned but with a 404 status code when you look at the HTTP response.

This is affecting everything that uses POST, including login. I did manage to get it to log in by changing the 'action' attribute of the login form to point to '/' using Firefox's web developer tools, but lots of other things didn't work and the admin menu occasionally disappeared.

Thought it might be a caching issue so manually truncated all the cache tables but that made no difference. There appeared to be an issue with a non-existent temp folder so I created the one it was expecting with 777 perms (as I couldn't change the setting because form submission wouldn't work...) but it wasn't this either. Clean URLs are working fine.

Never seen anything like this before. Any ideas most appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the `clean urls` in Drupal (just guessing). Are you sure that your new server supports clean urls? You can check it at `admin/config/search/clean-urls`. You might want to use `?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls`, it is not accessible directly. And if the server passes the clean URL test, then check if you have copied the `.htaccess` file properly.

Comment: Thanks Ajit but that isn't it, clean URLs are enabled and work fine. I've just tried running it on a different server, and have the same problem, but all fine on my dev box. I've checksummed the .htaccess in both places and they are identical. I think it *must* be a config issue that refers to the dev box, but haven't found it yet...

Comment: Ajit - I take it back, I'd forgotten to enable mod_rewrite and mod_headers! What I was amazed about was that clean URLs were working at all without them. I think this is because .htaccess points 404s to Drupal, which will then interpret the requested URL and show the appropriate page, but of course Apache is sending a 404 header. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you found the solution.

Comment: Whoever provided the solution please add that as answer and mark it as accepted and solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what seems to be the answer to this question (taken from a comment from OPer below the question):

> I'd forgotten to enable mod_rewrite and mod_headers! What I was amazed about was that clean URLs were working at all without them. I think this is because .htaccess points 404s to Drupal, which will then interpret the requested URL and show the appropriate page, but of course Apache is sending a 404 header.