# Post request not working Drupal and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7, ubuntu-14.04

In my ubuntu 14.04 OS machine for drupal 7 login not working, may be it is not only login but all post request not working here. For the same filesystem and codebase it works fine in windows 7 machine.

Here is my apache server configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName somedomain.local

DocumentRoot "/home/mycompany/Development/Projects/Drupal/cbb"

<Directory "/home/mycompany/Development/Projects/Drupal/cbb/">

   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

   AllowOverride All

   Require all granted    

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

for above configuration when i try to submit data for login it showing..
"**NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://somedomain.local/user**".

**#UPDATE**:

I just find out that login not working only from www.domainname.local/user path but if this login form in homepage sidebar it works fine, for all of drupal sire in ubuntu machine. With this no error message also not display.

I am in trouble for two of my drupal site in Ubuntu machine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please check your server logs and apache logs for any specific errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check if .htaccess file present in drupal root directory.
2. Check if you've added your domain to /etc/hosts file

   ```
   127.0.0.1 domain.name
   ```
3. Domains with 'www' and without it are totally different. Add both to /etc/hosts and to apache's config file to avoid problems.
4. Clear cache to avoid previous domain name which could be stored in cache.

   ```
   drush cc all
   ```
5. If you've just added new site to apache's configuration be sure to run:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 graceful
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Your Apache vhost file looks like it has the key components set and I'm assuming that the .htaccess file exists in your document root and hasn't been modified from the Drupal default.

When you click on the login link in the sidebar, does it take you to http://somedomain.local?q=user/login ?

Your #update suggests that even though your Apache environment may be set up for "clean URLs", the feature is not enabled in Drupal at *Administer > Configuration > Search and metadata > Clean URLs*.

If modifying this compromises your access to Drupal, you can apply/disable this change via Drush (`drush vset clean_url 0 --yes`) or directly through MySQL (`UPDATE variable SET value = 's:1:"0";' WHERE name = 'clean_url';`) as per https://www.drupal.org/node/5590.

Also worth mentioning, seeing it on this related question ([Very strange Drupal 7 404 behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552621/very-strange-drupal-7-404-behaviour?rq=1)): make sure that Apache modules mod_rewrite and mod_headers are enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: To the OP, also make sure that the `.htaccess` file exists. You might have copied the files of the Drupal zip package with copy/paste (instead of using the extracted folder) and due to the fact that it's hidden it might not exist.

Comment: @James i can't login though, so it is not possible to visit dashboard and your defined path Administer > Configuration > Search and metadata > Clean URLs.

Comment: If you can't access the login page, try using the Drush or direct MySQL update to enable Clean URLs. If you're saying that you can't log in using the link from the dashboard, you're probably looking at a different kind of problem.